# JS to bring HTML element into view

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using the following code without a problem to scroll to an HTML element.

```
<?php 
if ($_SESSION['id']=="bed5") {
?>
<script>
document.getElementById('bed5').scrollIntoView(true);
</script>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

However I want to destroy the SESSION['id'] after the JS has scrolled to the HTML just ONCE in order to prevent the page repeatedly navigating to the scroll view. So at the end of my script after the JS above I have added.

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['id']); 
?>
```

However the addition of the UNSET function after the JS above is causing the JS to fail. Ie it does not scroll to view the HTML element...even just the once....as I had expected. In summary I just need to get the JS to render a single scroll event .... conditional on the session variable...ONCE.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here and how to solve the problem please?

Comment: What do you mean once? It would only scroll into view again if you reload the page by refreshing it or navigating to it again. Per page view it should only scroll once already.

Comment: It's not a good idea to throw random script tags in your HTML, especially when they're generated conditionally. A good way to do it would be to append a hash to the URL, then in your JS file, check if there's a hash and scroll to it that way.

Comment: yes exactly Golez...it is the refresh that is causing the problem. The surrounding script logic is pretty complex but in a nutshell I am using the page logic many times. So want to destroy the session variable ---hence my code with the session variable getting destroyed after the first use of the page. Any ideas?

Comment: adding hashes in this application wont work for me. I simply need to get the JS to scroll to the html once ---- even if there is a page refresh Samrap, But thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: are you starting session on this page? using `session_start()`

Comment: From what I understand, your page refresh itself in some conditions, right? Maybe that's the problem. An unexpected refresh somewhere causes the page reload itself so session var being unset before it actually does it's job...

Comment: yes there is a session_start() peter. Thank you.

Comment: HI Darth. The page resets when links are clicked in the menu. The menu calls php?var=$var vrsions of the same page. But even before a link is clicked my problem is as per the question....ie I run the JS scroll to view without the unset function after and no problem...JS works ok. But if I run the page with the unset function inserted after the JS the JS scroll to view fails to work. Nothing else has been changed. Really strange. For info...the reason I am unsetting the session var is so that when I do a refresh using the ?php links the scroll to view condition isn't triggered.

Comment: ok all sorted. Moved the unset so that it could only trigger on the condition of a change of page. thanks